# Flutter - Rest API Auth expiry

Tags: authentication, flutter, timer, token, logout

I am currently implementing Auth in my Flutter app using a REST API built in .Net.

The rest API returns a token and token expiry date, I am storing this information in Secure Storage.

The app consists of multiple pages (Scaffold).

My question is, how can I have a background task that watches the expiry date, and automatically logs the user out when the token is expired?

Here is the format my date is stored in "2019-07-31T11:25:46.2265012Z"

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do this as a background task and not do a check every time the app is opened? Then you could just create a simple method that checks the current date compares it to the token if for example it is 30+days since the token was issued then it will send user to the login page.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, the idea is to only allow the user to use the app within the given time period, and once that time is over, we want them to get logged out, even if the user is in the middle of using the app.

Comment: Thanks. If that is the case this package might be of some use as it also includes scheduling - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

Answer (score 0):

i think you can add another endpoint to your api to refresh the token every time the user enter the app so you send the saved token to this endpoint and it will respond with a new one

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, for security reasons we don't want the token to refresh, we want the user to have to login again.

Comment: it's completely secure this way too!

Comment: Yes it is, and I have built multiple apps that work that way, however, the business requirements for this app are slightly different. they want the user to get logged out as soon as the timer expires.

Answer (score 0):

create a static method that is initialized with the token time when the user logs-in. This method should be called at logged page. The method should be something like this;

```
var tokenTime;    //tokenTime should be initialized when user signin. 

static void checkValidity(){
    Future.delay(duration: Duration(milliseconds: tokenTime), (){ logout();});
}
```

To avoid that the user stops the app to refresh the token, you can store in SharePrefference

Answer (score 0):

here's a Dart function that takes in the **expireInSeconds** and **loginTime** as strings in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" and checks if the token has expired:

```
bool isTokenExpired(int expireInSeconds, String loginTime) {
  DateTime loginDateTime = DateTime.parse(loginTime);
  DateTime expiryDateTime = loginDateTime.add(Duration(seconds: expireInSeconds));
  DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.now();
  return currentDateTime.isAfter(expiryDateTime);
}
```

You can call this function with the **expireInSeconds** and **loginTime** values to determine if the token has expired. The function returns true if the token has expired, and false otherwise.

**Here's an example usage:**

```
int expireInSeconds = 3600; // 1 hour
String loginTime = '2023-02-18 12:00:00';
bool tokenExpired = isTokenExpired(expireInSeconds, loginTime);
if (tokenExpired) {
  print('Token has expired');
} else {
  print('Token is still valid');
}
```

You can add these variables to your shared_preferences for future usage!

Answer (score -1):

here is an answer for it. Use schedular binding that can rebuild a widget passing ur token duration to it, so that as the duration ends the schedular binder is called executing a function for signing in again the user

@override

```
void initState() {    
 SchedulerBinding.insta``nce.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  //add your login function here
});}
```

Comment: This answer may be technically correct, but it is grammatically confusing. Try improving the wording of your explanation.